# insert a <img> in an PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

I'm using an PDF generator (DomPDF) to create a PDF with an HTML template. 
I want to put an image in the PDF I'm generating but it won't work. The path is 100% right but the picture just won't appear. At the place where the picture should be, "Image not found or type unknown" is written.

Does anyone know a way how I can load in image and load it in a PDF file?

Comment: Are you using the image path or URL? (You should be using the path. Preferably the absolute one)

Comment: <img src="/public/formular/image.png" width=100% height=120> - thats how I'm trying it

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf

Comment: Try echoing `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to be sure your path is correct.

Comment: the path is correct, I tried to view the picture on a normal html document and it worked. Just on the PDF it doesn't get inserted

Comment: I also tried it with an JPG - but its the same result

Comment: Download latest version of DomPdf and check.

Comment: I did - I've downloaded it yesterday and it's the latest version

Comment: I've found this : http://blog.skunkbad.com/php/dompdf-image-not-found-or-type-unknown -- the user said that I need to add those lines to allow using images. Where do I need to put these lines?