# How to include s3 url inside pdf files dompdf.

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zend-framework2, dompdf

My s3 url is https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/test.png

```
its working fine on browser and showing image not found after including it on pdf file.   

$pdf = new \DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel(); 
$pdf->setOption("filename", $filename); 
$pdf->setOption("paperSize", "a4"); 
$pdf->setOption("paperOrientation", "landscape"); 
$dompdf = new \DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render(); 
$pdfCode = $dompdf->output(); 
file_put_contents('path_to_pdf/test.pdf', $pdfCode);
```

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: Have you confirmed that dompdf has read/write access to the temp directory specified in your configuration? Do you get any error messages (i.e. from PHP)?

Comment: PDF created successfully but its showing image not found with cross sign. I'm also included images that are present in local server, its working fine. issue only with s3 images. Thanks

Comment: you can try my solution .  you need to check this.....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf/75243734#75243734

Answer (score 1):

If you use Laravel, you need to add this to your blade.

```
@php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    $content = Storage::get('vinylmaster.png');
    $imageData = base64_encode($content);
    $src = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $imageData;
@endphp

<img src="{{$src}}">
```

if you are not on Laravel, try [Embedding images in a PDF file with PHP and DOMPDF](http://www.yitz.com/embed-images-dompdf)