# Symfony 4: Image not found or type unknown after downloading PDF using dompdf

Tags: symfony4, dompdf

I am getting the error

> "Image not found or type unknown"

after downloading PDF in Symfony 4 using dompdf package.

My method in my controller class:

```php
public function dompdf(EvaluationRepository $evaluationRepository)
{
    // Configure Dompdf according to your needs
    $pdfOptions = new Options();
    $pdfOptions->set('IsFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
    $pdfOptions->set('IsHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $pdfOptions->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
    $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');

    // Instantiate Dompdf with our options
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);
    // Retrieve the HTML generated in our twig file
    $html = $this->renderView('analyse/approbation/mypdf.html.twig', [
        'evaluations' => $evaluationRepository->findAll(),
    ]);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf", [
        "Attachment" => false
    ]);
}
```

My HTML twig-template

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<caption>
  <img src="{{ pathToPublic }}/images/cpmpss.jpg" align="middle" style="width:100%">
</caption>
```

**Note:** **pathToPublic** variable globale in **twig.yaml** contain the absolute pathe

```
pathToPublic: '%kernel.project_dir%/public'
```

Please suggest how can I fix it.

Comment: Where do you get the error `"Image not found or type unknown" ` ? In the browser? As a PHP exception? While opening the downloaded PDF with program X/Y? Please be more specific.

Comment: i got this error when i opend the downloaded PDF

Comment: Did you try `<img src="{{ asset('images/cpmpss.jpg') }}">` ?

Comment: Yes!! but isn't working

Answer (score 0):

those two steps helped me to solve this issue :

firstly enable isRemoteEnabled on pdfOptions.

```
        $pdfOptions->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
```

Here example of my code :

```
 public function __construct(){
    $this->domPdf = new Dompdf();

    $pdfOptions = new Options();
    $pdfOptions->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    $pdfOptions->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $pdfOptions->setTempDir('temp'); // temp folder with write permission

    $this->domPdf->setOptions($pdfOptions);

}
```

And then on the twig use absolute path as the fallowing :

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('build/logo.jpg')) }}" alt="logo">
```